# Removing special characters (¡) from a string

Tags: python, unicode, special-characters

I am trying to write into a file from a collection. The collection has special characters like ¡ which create a problem. For example the content in the collection has details like:

> {..., Name: ¡Hi!, ...}

Now I am trying to write the same into a file but I get the error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa1' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have tried the using the solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109970/linux-python-encoding-a-unicode-string-for-print) but in vain. It will be great if someone could help me with this :)

So the example goes like this:

I have a collection which has the following details

```
{ "_id":ObjectId("5428ead854fed46f5ec4a0c9"), 
   "author":null,
   "class":"culture",
   "created":1411967707.356593,
   "description":null,
   "id":"eba9b4e2-900f-4707-b57d-aa659cbd0ac9",
   "name":"¡Hola!",
   "reviews":[

   ],
   "screenshot_urls":[

   ]
}
```

Now I try to access the `name` entry here from the collection and I do that by iterating it over the collection i.e.

```
f = open("sample.txt","w");

for val in exampleCollection:
   f.write("%s"%str(exampleCollection[val]).encode("utf-8"))

f.close();
```

Comment: Did you try the accepted answer in the link provided?

Comment: Can you show us more details about how you actually encode the collection and it's not working?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I have edited the question and provided and example. 
- @blackmamba

Comment: I have edited and added a code snippet for better understanding the question that I asked. Sorry about posting an ambiguous question. - @bourbaki4481472

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to remove characters you don't want is to specify the characters you do.

```
>>> import string
>>> validchars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + ' '
>>> s = '¡Hi there!'
>>> clean = ''.join(c for c in s if c in validchars)
>>> clean
'Hi there'
```

If some forms of punctuation are okay, add them to validchars.

Answer (score 1):

This will remove all the characters in the string which are not valid ASCII.

```
>>> '¡Hola!'.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
'Hola!'
```

Alternatively, you can [write the file as UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934160/write-to-utf-8-file-in-python), which can represent nearly all characters on Earth.

Answer (score 0):

As one user posted on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20) page, you should take a look at the Unicode tutorial in the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

What's happening is you're trying to use a character that's outside the ASCII range, which is a mere 128 symbols. There's a really great article on this I found a while back, which I'll try to find and post here.

Edit: ah, here it is: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to convert unicode to ascii in "strict" mode:

```
>>> help(str.encode)
Help on method_descriptor:

encode(...)
    S.encode([encoding[,errors]]) -> object

    Encodes S using the codec registered for encoding. encoding defaults
    to the default encoding. errors may be given to set a different error
    handling scheme. Default is 'strict' meaning that encoding errors raise
    a UnicodeEncodeError. Other possible values are 'ignore', 'replace' and
    'xmlcharrefreplace' as well as any other name registered with
    codecs.register_error that is able to handle UnicodeEncodeErrors.
```

You probably want something like one of the following:

```
s = u'¡Hi there!'

print s.encode('ascii', 'ignore')    # removes the ¡
print s.encode('ascii', 'replace')   # replaces with ?
print s.encode('ascii','xmlcharrefreplace') # turn into xml entities
print s.encode('ascii', 'strict')    # throw UnicodeEncodeErrors
```